# Python speech recognition library prints to the screen when recording audio

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am recording user's voice using python speech_recognition library. The program shows a result even though I do not print it to the screen. How can I eliminate this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to package github issue tracker entry [Transcript confidence results are always printed out even without asking to print it #662](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/662) this is result of some.. recent changes in package source code.

Can be solved by downgrading package to version 3.8.1 `pip install SpeechRecognition==3.8.1`